# How to access a static member of the class in a decorator for a method of that class?

Tags: typescript

With TypeScript 5.0 we got the new decorator APIs and I want to use them to automatically provide parameters for a method, that are provided by a static property in the same class. So, I defined the decorator parameters and the decorator factory like this:

```js
type TargetFunction<This, Args extends unknown[], Return> = (this: This, ...args: Args) => Return;

class Throwable extends Error {} // Only for demonstration.

export interface ITestParameters {
    dataProvider?: string;
    expectedExceptions?: typeof Throwable;
}

export const Test = <T extends ITestParameters>(param: T) => {
    return <This, Args extends unknown[], Return>(target: TargetFunction<This, Args, Return>,
        context: ClassMethodDecoratorContext<This, TargetFunction<This, Args, Return>>) => {
        return function (this: This, ...args: Args): Return {
            if (param.dataProvider) {
                const newArgs = (this as any)[param.dataProvider] as Args;
                return target.call(this, ...newArgs) as Return;
            }

            return target.call(this, ...args) as Return;
        };
    };
};
```

This factory is then applied in a test class:

```js
class SubList {
    @Test({ dataProvider: "modifiable" })
    public testMod(list: number[], from: number, to: number): void {
        console.log(list, from, to);
    }

    public static modifiable: [number[], number, number] = [[1, 2, 3], 4, 5];
}

    (new SubList()).testMod([], 0, 0); // error, newArgs is undefined
```

In the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAFQIYCcDmMwDECuA7AYzAEsB7PAHgQAtiBnAGjgEF064YAPMGPAE3b4A1nlIB3PAG0AukwBKmHCjwA+OAF44ACjC06ALkR6mAOjOo0BlmwCUGtQrBK8AblCgCAGyR12NFOJIAEae8Fw8-OwAoigBKHAA3nAAvnAA9GlwAPJ4nhBwAGak8XwwALbkdGAoSCTkJu4gxHg8KAVIBPAAkggwVQAKqEhlmDAo7AmgcNNwfLVI-QEAbsSlKAD8hlUozWhuIDMcnLBEMHxRnJ1QdXh0m3CQsKQFRgFiwaH7yY0ElWCIfX+mioRwiAjgPUBgxqI1adBUWigQzKhgQdnUakmBxmKEUyjgVGM1ksoN44OEogkMnkeNUOgsmFRDOw+CIZEoNHoTFYlhpTmUKgYU0OM1+LXChgAwt5fABZTDUUh8AAiMF+NTAxUl5B43EJXMQzNwhBu+sYxPNjmcKhU6MxwpFcFx-LwhVZN20unoqKJZhMFisPLoNkMVvxWMdjuIL0RyJMczAC2WqzGdgjkYzYqqcDwMDEQY0nr0cB8JbwEBskiRMPj80WpBWa2kJfYQf2GYzzucD2ZJgISE8nh0vrMufzthbcDDrgdHe+IFnndpPfQmD7A6HXvNfoDdlL0-bkeSh+mx9AZ4XIC8PnYAGUcEEADL0f7p6YAAV6VS0SQTSYbKYoIYABEFR8NGxAfDAwEpDYs5QA+njEAQDyArKSpaEhVSGHgOBlEEYzUoUAQojmeEESgTCajh5GpoYSykKsiSLqKlSkKEJieKQaCYS+TAFCRVGkDYJ4pI0hwISEyFwFUtTSWBEFQYYki4fhhGyGRamUZpFHNpokiSAAjEwABMTAAMwaQALEwACs0hfI0WhjnA95Pi+Wg2DYJg8FU6F8FoREAAxMEFInpJkYxxEwY4FvQcD4KUBTNGcQA) this code is mostly fine, except that I can't access  the static property in the class whose name is given as factory parameter. What needs to be changed to make this work?

I know there's the `this` parameter, but that cannot be used to access the static method. I also tried `this.prototype[param.dataProvider]` but that also gave an error.

Comment: Too many syntax errors, unused type parameters, and type assertions.

Comment: Your playground link is broken; could you fix it?   Also make sure it doesn't have any errors unrelated to your question, so that we're not distracted by them.

Comment: (continued) Actually you say the code is "mostly fine" but it seems like there are some fairly basic problems.  Presumably the static thing at the `param.dataProvider` is a *zero-arg method* that returns... an *array* of argument lists?  So you'd have to *call* it (which you haven't done) and then... pick some element of the result... to be `newArgs`?  I'd say iterate over all of them but you're `return`ing the result, so ❓❓.

Comment: (continued more) If I fix those and ignore all the other issues I get [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WP81zW). Is that what you're looking for? Either way you probably should fix the code so that the only problem is that you didn't use `this.constructor` and not all that... other stuff.  Please [edit] the question to fix these problems and then let me know if the `this.constructor` approach is what you're looking for so I can write up an answer explaining.

Comment: About which errors are you talking? There's only one error in this code and that's the one I want to get fixed with my question. Of course, I couldn't test the code yet, since it does not build. But it looks like you came very close to a solution. The values are injected, just like planned, with your version of the code.

Comment: I'd be happy to [edit] the question to fix the issues I'm talking about, if you're okay with that, possibly to something like [this version](//tsplay.dev/Wk8Ejw).  If you're not okay with that then I guess I should detail every issue again, but it's mostly contained in my previous comments. Either way: • the playground link is broken • if the "one error" is a compiler error, please include it explicitly in the question so this is a [mre] • TS will by default still emit JS code even if there's a compiler error, so you can definitely test the code.  -- Let me know how you want to proceed here.

Comment: Hey @jcalz, thanks for the offer. Sure, go ahead and edit the question, as well as provide an answer. I updated the link already and it works fine for me. And it only shows one error, though once fixed other problems will certainly show up.

Comment: Okay, done.  I guess in your original question you got a compiler error and it stopped you from making progress, but the compiler error isn't really the thing stopping you from accessing the static method.  It was mostly a distraction, so I edited the question to be primarily "how to access a static member" from the title. Hope it's close enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decorated method is invoked with a [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) context of an *instance* of the decorated class.  But static class properties are attached to the class *constructor* and not directly on any instance.  So in order to access a static property of a class from an instance of the class, you need to look at its [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) property.  That means instead of `this[param.dataProvider]` you need `(this.constructor)[param.dataProvider]`.

TypeScript doesn't strongly type the `constructor` property of class instances, for reasons laid out in [microsoft/TypeScript#3841](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841).  So in order to get that to compile you'll need to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions). It looks like you were already prepared to use type assertions inside the decorator function so this is just another one.  I'm just going to assert that `this` is [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) to suppress errors and not worry about it too much:

```
const newArgs = (this as any).constructor[param.dataProvider] as Args;
```

Now when we run the code the decorated method indeed gets its arguments from the static class property, as desired:

```
(new SubList()).testMod([], 0, 0); // [1, 2, 3], 4, 5
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAFQIYCcDmMwDECuA7AYzAEsB7PAHgQAtiBnAGjgEF064YAPMGPAE3b4A1nlIB3PAG0AukwBKmHCjwA+OAF44ACjC06ALkR6mAOjOo0BlmwCUGtQrBK8AblCgCAGyR12NFOJIAEae8Fw8-OwAoigBKHAA3nAAvnAA9GlwAPJ4nhBwAGak8XwwALbkdGAoSCTkJu4gxHg8KAVIBPAAkggwVQAKqEhlmDAo7AmgcNNwfLVI-QEAbsSlKAD8hlUozWhuIDMcnLBEMHxRnJ1QdXh0m3CQsKQFRgFiwaH7yY0ElWCIfX+mioRwiAjgPUBgxqI1adBUWigQzKhgQdnUakmBxmKEUyjgVGM1ksoN44OEogkMnkeNUOgsmFRDOw+CIZEoNHoTFYlhpTmUKgYU0OM1+LXChgAwt5fABZTDUUh8AAiMF+NTAxUl5B43EJXMQzNwhBu+sYxPNjmcKhU6MxwpFcFx-LwhVZN20unoqKJZhMFisPLoNkMVvxWMdjuIL0RyJMczAC2WqzGdgjkYzYqqcDwMDEQY0nr0cB8JbwEBsJiz1RwRGKkiRMPj80WpBWa2kJfYQf2GYzzucD2ZVaQnk8Ol9Zlz+dsXbgYdcDr73xAS-7tKH6EwI7HE4NfoDdlLC97keSp+m59AV9XIC8PnYAGUcEEADL0f7p6YAAV6VS0SQJkmbYpighgAEQVHw0bEB8MDgSkNhLlAL6eMQBAPICspKloaFVIYeA4GUQRjNShQBCiOZESRKBMJqBHUamhhLKQqyJGuoqVKQoQmJ4pBoLhH5MAUFF0aQNgXikjSHChIToXAVS1PJUEwXBhiSIRxGkbIVFabRuk0Z2miSJIACMTAAExMAAzDpAAsTAAKzSF8jRaNOcDPm+H5aDYlY8FU2F8FoZEAAxMKFEnpJkZmWTZ9lOUAA)